# python django make a subclass use the parents table

Tags: python, django, django-models, subclass

Hoi, this is my first post and I am pretty new to django.
[Edit: changed "from" to "mfrom"]

I have a generic class like

```
class Message(models.Model):
    mfrom = models.TextField()
    text = models.TextField()

    def beautify(self, text):
        '''replace emoticons with images'''
        return text

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text = self.beautify(self.text)
        super(Message, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and I have a few sources where messages are coming from that need different handling, some (like XMPP) will come from non HTTP request sources, but external scripts.

So I thought I'd make subclasses of Message for the different types like

```
class MessageXMPP(Message):
    def load_from_XMPP(self, xmppmsg):
        self.mfrom = xmppmsg.mfrom
        self.text = xmppmsg.text

class MessageJSON(Message):
    def load_from_JSON(self, jsonmsg):
        self.mfrom = jsonmsg.mfrom
        self.text = jsonmsg.text
```

If I now call the save() method of the above two classes django tries to save it to the MessageXMPP resp. MessageJSON tables, while I want the data to be stored in the Message table (and not have MessageXMPP resp. MessageJSON tables created at all).

Is there a way to not create a Message object and copy the values over, but have the subclasses write to the Message table?

Comment: Don´t use `from` as variable, is a python keyword.

Comment: Here you should be able to find the answer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/. Also in `two scoops of django` I saw the solution to this, but I cant remember. Proxy approach maybe?

Comment: Why don't just put a function called `load` in the `Message` model, and delegate it's behaviour to `load_from_JSON`, `load_from_XMPP`, etc..?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you have separate model classes here. You should really just have one class with the different methods. Even better, since these are creation methods, you should define a custom Manager which returns the instantiated Message.

However, if you insist on having separate classes, you should make them [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) so that they do not reference their own tables:

```
class MessageJSON(Message):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: Thanks! My models are of course a lot more complex with quite some methods and I'd like to keep the code for the various sources separated and not everything in one class.
I will try the `proxy = True` and also have a look at `Managers`.